# Find all the capital and lowercase Fs in it and insert a capital K right before each one of them

Tags: c#, regex

How do I solve this problem. You are given a string text consisting of English letters and spaces. Find all the capital and lowercase Fs in it and insert a capital K right before each one of them.

```
string addKbeforeFs(string text) {
string output = Regex.Replace(text, "([F])_?([K])", "$1 $2");
}
```

Comment: `s.Replace("f", "Kf").Replace("F", "KF")`?

Comment: or with regex _Regex.Replace(text, "([Ff])", "K$1")_

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That sure looks like an answer, not a comment.  Care to write one?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regex you may use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(text, "f", "K$&", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Here, `f` is matched in a case insensitive way (thanks to `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`) and the matches are replaced with `K` and the same variant of `f` (`F` or `f`) by means of the `$&` backreference.

However, you may achieve what you want with a mere chained `string.Replace`:

```
var result = text.Replace("f", "Kf").Replace("F", "KF");
```